# An alternative way on how to resize image to target filesize in Android

Tags: android

I am aware of the sheer amount of answers regarding this. However, I had a simpler method which I would like to discuss with the larger community to see if there is a blindspot in my method.

Assuming you have a image filesize of 4MB, resolution of 4032 x 2268, and JPEG encoding.
You need a target image filesize of not more than 2MB, resolution to be scaled down accordingly and JPEG.

Image file size is calculated as such:

```
originFilesize = width  x height  x bytePerPixel x compressionRatio
targetFilesize = width" x height" x bytePerPixel x compressionRatio
```

compressionRatio is how well an image can be compressed. BytePerPixel will 3 for JPEG (RGB) and 4 for PNG (RGB + alpha channel)

Given that the content of originFilesize will be similar to targetFilesize (just the scaled down version) and the image encoding will be the same. We can assume that BytePerPixel and compressionRatio for both are the same.

This will give us the following:

```
    originFilesize = width  x height 
    targetFilesize = width" x height"
```

We can derive the resolution of our target image as such:

```
    scaleRatio = targetFilesize/originFilesize
    width"  = width x scaleRatio
    height" = height x scaleRatio
```

Here is the code in Kotlin:

```
val MB = 1024 * 1024
val scaleRatio = (2 * MB).toDouble() / originFile.length()
val newWidth = (bitmap.width * scaleRatio).toInt()
val newHeight = (bitmap.height * scaleRatio).toInt()

val scaledBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true)

val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos)

val targetFile = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)
targetFile.use {
            it.write(bos)
        }
```

Excuse me for the brevity of the code. I just put it all the necessary details. Here is one of the many test logs:

```
Original Filesize = 4374209 bytes
scaleRatio: 0.47943571054789563
File Dimension: 4032 x 2268
Scale File Dimension: 1933 x 1087
filesize saved is: 1690468 bytes
```

Consistently, I am getting less than 2MB which what I need. I also noticed that if I compressed to PNG, that will increase my image filesize. The final resized image size do have a smaller scale ratio (1690468/4374209 = 0.38 rather than 0.479). I suspect this comes from the assumption I made on compressionRatio.

Question now is whether there is a blindspot or flaw in this resize logics which I can't see?

Comment: What I would do is decrease the size requirement gradually. Try 1MB 512KB 256KB 128KB.... If you get relatively the same results, then your algorithm is probably in a good place.

Comment: thank you for the tip. I tried yesterday. It seems that if the picture has lots of identical colors in an area - this logic does not hold true. In fact, the scaled down picture after compression actually has a bigger filesize ! I did rotate the image before scaling it down. Perhaps this might cause an issue there.

Comment: I noticed that if I re-ran it twice, I usually get to the filesize I need. I am not sure if this is the right approach.